# Right permissions to .git directory on server

Tags: permissions, git, apache2.4, github

I am working on deployment of application on ubuntu `trusty` server. I am using `git` ssh and web-hooks(deploy-keys) to deploy the code on server after its pushed to the master from local repository,reference [here](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/).
To be able to call the script on the server using web-hook,I have a PHP file,`test.php` which executes the shell script written in `git.sh` for calling git commands.
The php and shell are below.

```
<?php       
//echo "THis is a test file on a test repo for testing the deploy functionality using github webhooks!!!!";
echo exec('whoami');
echo exec('sh -x /var/www/iq/deploy-test/git.sh');
?>


#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
```

I had to change the ownership of `.git` repo to `www-data` as the user of apache executes scripts over `http`. Is it a good practice to have the user as apache on .git folder. Are there any security implications on this appproach? My regular user is `ubuntu`. 
*If not,what would be the ideal way to manage ownership and  permissions on `.git` repo. What updates do I need to make to the sudoers file if needed.*